# permission for the `www-data` user to execute a binary file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, binary-files

How can I give permission for the `www-data` user of Ubuntu machine to execute a command installed in `/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: **What exactly** makes you think that `www-data` does not have the permission already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, run the following command:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/_filename_
```

If there is no "x" (execute) permission for other users, run this command to give read/write/execute permissions to owner, read/execute permission to group and read/execute permission to other users.

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/_filename_
```

See also `chmod(1)` manual page.

Also file may not run for other reasons besides permissions - inaccessible shared libraries, wrong PATH in environment + running via short name, inaccessible interpreter (if it's a script) etc.